# How to connect an email sign-in to firebase server in Xcode 13

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have tried a few ways to connect to the firebase server with a google sign in, but nothing I'm doing is working. Could someone direct me to a resource or show me how to connect to it. Thanks so much.

Comment: It's not clear whether you're talking about iOS or macOS, but in general, the place to start is [the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/google-signin). If you've tried that, it's probably a good idea to detail where you got stuck and when went wrong.

Comment: What is the issue you are facing ?